# Search 3D list for single Item

Tags: python, list, csv

I am creating a leaderboard creating system, where it checks if the Name is already in the Database, if not it adds it, and if it is it replaces the name and score.

```
import csv
winner =["Player", 100]
def leaderboardsave(winner):
    fileCSV = open('scores.csv')
    dataCSV = csv.reader(fileCSV)
    playersScores = list(dataCSV)
    winnerName = winner[0]
    winner_index = playersScores.find(winnerName)
    if winner_index > -1:
        playersScores[winner_index] = winner
    else:
        playersScores.append(winner)
leaderboardsave(winner)
```

The CSV is saved like this:

```
Player, 20
Player2, 40
Player3, 30
Player4, 60
```

whenever I run

```
    winner_index = playersScores.find(winnerName)
```

it returns "'list' object has no attribute 'find'"
Any other ways to find where the item is in the list? When i tried using .index, it wouldnt find it, i assume as it is looking for a list, not a single string?

Comment: `.index()` only works on lists like `[x, y, z]`; the list you have is like `[[x, 1], [y, 2], [z, 3]]`.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Thank you, any ideas on alternatives or packages that include a .find function?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because `playerScores` is a list object and a `list` object doesn't have a `find` function.

You can traverse a list to find a value by looping:

`winner_index = [index for index, value in enumerate(playerScores) if value == winnerName]`

Comment: Thanks, However when I run this, it returns `SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ')' does not match opening parenthesis '['`. I have no clue about the syntax about what is above, any ideas?

Comment: @Zenot1c I believe there is a typo in Kenan's answer; the correct code is `[index for index, value in enumerate(playerScores) if value == winnerName]`. There is an extra parenthesis at the end.